# Ffmpeg hls segment stop segmenting after 5300 segments

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to make a http video streaming using hls, ffmpeg and raspivid and I need a replay time of 1 day but after 5300 segments ffmpeg stop segmenting and continue writing the video to the 5301 segment for the end of the day (5300/5301 is an average number, +- 50 segments)
I have plenty of storage space, my camera can record all the day. The only problem is ffmpeg who decide to stop segmenting after 5300 segments

Thank you and sorry for my poor english ^^

Here is my streaming script:

````
base="/var/www/html/"

set -x

rm -rf /var/www/html/ppc/saves/live live.h264
mkdir -p /var/www/html/ppc/saves/live

# fifos seem to work more reliably than pipes - and the fact that the
# fifo can be named helps ffmpeg guess the format correctly.
mkfifo live.h264
raspivid -a 1036 -w 1640 -h 1232 -fps 15 -t 37200000 -b 1500000 -o - | psips > live.h264 &

# Letting the buffer fill a little seems to help ffmpeg to id the stream
sleep 2

# Need ffmpeg around 1.0.5 or later. The stock Debian ffmpeg won't work.
# I'm not aware of options apart from building it from source. I have
# Raspbian packags built from Debian Multimedia sources. Available on
# request but I don't want to post them publicly because I haven't cross
# compiled all of Debian Multimedia and conflicts can occur.
ffmpeg -y -r 15 -i live.h264 -f alsa  -i default:CARD=C525 -r:a 48000 -ac 1 -af adelay=32s -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -r 30 \
 -f segment \
 -segment_time 7 \
 -segment_format mpegts \
 -segment_list /var/www/html/ppc/saves/live/live.m3u8 \
 -segment_list_flags live \
 -segment_list_type m3u8 \
 -initial_offset -9 \
 -strict 2 /var/www/html/ppc/saves/live/%08d.ts < /dev/null```
````

Comment: Your raspivid has `-t 37200000` which is in milliseconds so 37200s. With `-segment_time 7`, that much data is consumed in ~5300 portions.